# What are the differences in ingress portal shield types?

Tags: ingress

I have collected a few different types of shields, with different colours and of differing rarity.

I assume the rarer shield types are more powerful in some way but I can't find any information on it.

**Question** : *What different types of shield are available and what are the differences between them?*

More detail, I currently have three shield types:

- Green (Common)
- Purple (Rare)
- Pink (Very Rare)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @fbueckert but as the second tag specifically mentioned portal shields, are you sure it's extraneous? I would have kept it and removed the more general 'ingress' tag if anything... please advise.

Comment: Usually we use just game tags; if we get enough questions for a game, we start breaking it up into specific sections, such as the one you made.  If it turns out that Ingress gets a ton (ie. 200/300) of questions, sure, put it back!  Until then, though, we just finished a massive tag cleanup effort, so we try to limit the number of tags. :)

Comment: OK, that makes sense, thanks for the explanation. :)

Comment: Happy to help. :)  This is a good question, so here's hoping you get a great answer to go with it.

Comment: Good question, do you know what shields do?

Comment: Yes, I know that they help defend portals by reducing attackers XM, but I wasn't aware there were different _types_ of shields and wanted to know if anyone had info on the damage different types did / the reduction in power for number of shields etc. I've added more details in the question...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you select a shield to deploy in the Upgrade-menu, it actually shows you their different parameters (just like for resonators it shows how much the range would increase *iff* deployed).

The values for the shields are:

- Common - MITIGATION 22(+6)
- Rare - MITIGATION 22(+8)
- Very Rare - MITIGATION 22(+10)

Of course it's a different matter to figure out how those values relate to burst-absorption.

Comment: Can you find a portal and make note of the data?

Comment: Will do, just need to get near a portal and will update the question. Thanks for this answer, seems we're close!

Comment: @Daenyth the values are 6, 8 and 10 of something I don't understand :)

Comment: I've edited this answer (awaiting peer review) to show more info I've gathered - I'm not marking it answered yet as I don't know what exactly MITIGATION means... adding that info to this answer will qualify it (for me) as the correct answer.

Comment: Presumably 'mitigation' means it reduces the effect of an XMP Burst.  What I'm wondering is when we might start to see other types of Portal Shields that have an effect on some of the *other* parameters listed...

* Absorption: will that mean that it re-powers the resonator somehow?

  I look forward to it - in the current game the portals seem to change hands far too easily, though it's great for leveling up both sides.

Comment: So the three characteristics for a shield appear to be:

 * Mitigation
 * Absorption
 * Reflection

Has anyone seen a portal shield which provides *other* than "Mitigation"?  I've only seen the three "Mitigation" ones.

Answer (score 12):

New Shield mitigation (again)

- Common - 30
- Rare - 40
- Very Rare - 60
- Very Rare AXA - 70 *[(What is this?)](http://www.fevgames.net/axa-shields-revealed/)*

*Was 6,8,10 at first, later changed to 10,20,30, then to 20,30,50.

1 shield mitigation is 1% of reduced damage. The reduction is hard capped at 95%, though the mitigation can be higher than that.

*When the shield mitigation changed the first time, it was necessary to 'refresh' your inventory by dropping shields on ground and collecting them again. It is not necessary any more and all old shields should have the new values. For more informations read the following link.

[What is the formula for damage mitigation in Ingress?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120525/what-is-the-formula-for-damage-mitigation-in-ingress/133484#133484)