# What is the advantage of VERY-RARE items over Common or Rare items?

Tags: ingress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the differences in ingress portal shield types?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/94656/what-are-the-differences-in-ingress-portal-shield-types)

I had a portal shield marked as common, which I used.

When I hacked some portals I got some more portal shields - this time marked as RARE and VERY_RARE. I placed these 2 portal shields on the same portal.

What is the difference between these items? Is it uncommon to get rare items - do they provide greater shielding ability?

Comment: @bwarner I wouldn't say so... How many close votes have I got so far?

Comment: @LiamW: It does seem like a dup so far, since your only example is portal shields which is covered by the other question. Do you have examples of other rare items?

Comment: Confirmed that only 'answer' so far is wrong, I think this is a dup as well - VTC